# How to create a ui_component form which should be come as slide while click on admin grid edit action

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent, adminform, ui

> How to create a  ui_component form which should be come as slider when we click  on edit action then that form which I have created should be come as  slide and save and back button also should be there it should be look like this please see below screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be this blog is help you.https://aureatelabs.com/blog/add-view-button-in-admin-grid-to-open-a-view-page-in-slide-window-in-magento-2/

Comment: @JigarPatel It will only show the phtml file content , I just wanted to show ui_component form data